# Get range of string in iPhone sdk

Tags: iphone, string

I am developing an application that requires to get the substring in between x and y locations of a string like range between (120, 340).

Please suggest how I can achieve this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can achieve that using `substringWithRange:NSMakeRange`:

```
 NSLog([@"1234567890" substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(3, 5)]);
```

> Returns a string object containing the characters of the receiver that lie within a given range. [NSString Class Reference - substringWithRange](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/substringWithRange:)

Comment: I got it, [string substringFromIndex:fromIndex]; and [string substringToIndex:toIndex]; we can get the required string.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this...

```
NSString *strr = [NSString stringWithString:@"Hello"];

        for (int i =0; i<[strr length]; i++) {
            NSString *str1 = [strr substringFromIndex:i];
            CCLOG(@"str %d = %@",i,[str1 substringToIndex:1]);
        }
```